# NatTable cell selection provider

Tags: nattable

Although NatTable already has a class RowSelectionProvider, my data is provided through cells, not rows, so I cannot use this class. Is it possible to create a class CellSelectionProvider, or it would be too difficult?

What I want to do is select a cell in the NatTable, which is linked to an EObject. Then select the EObject in the editor and show its properties in the properties view. The first part I'm able to do, but not the second.

I've seen some tutorials about how connect to the properties view using JFace viewers as the selection provider, but nothing related to NatTable.

Answer (score 0):

The `ISelectionProvider` interface specifies a `getSelection()` and a `setSelection()` method. The selection in NatTable is implemented via the `SelectionLayer`. While it should be quite easy to implement `getSelection()` based on the `SelectionLayer` it could become quite difficult to implement `setSelection()` in a general way. Since you are working with a model based approach it is maybe possible for you to get the cell coordinates for the element that is sent via an `ISelection` to correctly implement `setSelection()`, but typically this is not possible as the same value in a column can be set for multiple rows.

Maybe you also don't need `setSelection()` and you can implement it empty as you only want to provide a selection to the properties view. But that also depends on your use case and what you want to achieve in whole.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't need a cellSelectionProvider.

Comment: I have an editor with an EMF model and I want to present the model in a table format, so I build a NatTable in a view and place the elements from the model in the table cells (each cell contains an EObject). When I click on a cell, the EObject is also selected in the model (I look for the EObject in the model tree and add a selection to it), but the Properties View isn't updated. 
This is my problem, I can't update the Properties View by clicking on a cell, just clicking on an EObject in the editor. Maybe it's not a NatTable issue, but related to Eclipse and I can't solve it. Thanks